# Properly Re-Asking My On-Hold Question

Tags: discussion, on-topic-ness, asking-questions, etiquette

I'm new to AE, so I am still learning the ropes of asking questions and the proper format of it. So far, I find the guidelines helpful, not only for getting better answers but for improving my own academic writing (avoiding tangents, vague arguments, etc). Which is why I am in a quandary.

After my question was put on-hold, I edited it to redefine my questions and make them possible to answer. [User aeismail suggested that I separate the two questions before asking again.](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/47691/i-got-dismissed-from-my-university-where-do-i-go-from-here) I want to proceed, but I am not sure what is the proper way. If I separate them do I delete the original post so I can avoid repeats of the same material, or should I link back to the original post as a reference point for both questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create one new post, and post the second question there. Then flag the first question for moderator attention so we can reopen it.